# R.. Is there any way to return corresponding index number after compare two vectors?

Tags: r

I've been really trying to solve it but could not figure it out.

Let's say I have 2 data frames with 1 column each.

For example,
df a looks like this.
(Numbers are row names of the values.)

```
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
6       f
7       g
8       h
9       i
```

and df b is like this (it has different length with df a).

```
1       o
2       p
3       a
4       m
5       g
```

What I want to do is that I want to look thru if any values in df b exist in df a and get row names(index?) of corresponding values in df a.
So in this case, since values in df b which are 'a' and 'g' of 3rd and 5th rows exist in 1st row and 7th row, I want to get 1 and 7 as return.

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `?which` and `?"%in%"`.

Comment: @Imo I think I should've not posted this one. Didn't know it was duplicated. Pretty noob here. Please understand but anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
dfa <- data.frame(col1=letters[1:9])
dfb <- data.frame(col2=c("o","p","a","m","g"))
which(dfa[,1] %in% dfb[,1])
[1] 1 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to get. Hope you have a great day today. Once again, thanks!